# What type of MUX to most effectively connect both sets of resistors at once?

Tags: microcontroller, operational-amplifier, multiplexer, differential

The following circuit is used PER CHANNEL, and I have 4 channels, to according scale the gain for our input signals on each channel.

However, each channel, has to be able to switch between 4 resistors top and bottom, in order for the gain to be effective for the input.

[image: DESIGN BELOW]

What type of analog MUX would you guys recommend for this to be able to avoid using tons of physical switches? I plan on using a teensy 4.0 MCU to program this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you would need two of these.

[image]

> TMUX1104 5-V, Low-Leakage-Current, 4:1 Precision Multiplexer.

- ultra low leakage current - 100pA
- rail to rail operation
- low ON state resistance - 2 ohms.
  [image]

Comment: But thats only for 1 channel? So I would need 8 for 4 channel?

There has to be a simpler way to do this.

Comment: They are bidirectional. You need one for the top section and one for the bottom.

Comment: Looks a sensible solution to me +1. Simpler solution - this looks simple. You asked for a MUX and you got one - you might be able to get dual versions so get cracking and find one because asking for product recommendations are generally off-topic on this site @BeshoyHanna.